# How to deal with error "can't find PInvoke DLL 'KbdAPI32.dll'"

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

In windows-mobile I get this error: `can't find PInvoke DLL 'KbdAPI32.dll'`

What is the cause and how can I solve it.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question. The most likely reason for this error is that one of your component references this dll and its not able to find it in the specified path.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code (or the library code) you are referring to that DLL. However, it doesn't exist.